# How do I Click on a Flash object with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have something like this:

```
<object id="myflash"></object>
```

I've tried making jQuery click the object like so:

```
$('#myflash').click();
```

But this doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to focus it, or actually click on a certain point?

You can probably use `.focus()` instead of `.click()` to focus the flash object.  If you need to click on a certain spot, you should create a method in ActionScript that does what you want the click to do, and then call it.  Your ActionScript will look something like this:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendTextToFlash", getTextFromJavaScript);
function getTextFromJavaScript(str):void {
    trace(str);
}
```

You then call the method with the name set in the `addCallback` call directly on the object:

```
flashObject.sendTextToFlash('My string');
```

See [this page](http://painteddigital.com/2008/calling-flash-as3-functions-from-javascript/) for more info and a method that will get the object or embed so that it works correctly in all browsers.